# How can I prevent Joomla 3 from filtering Picture elements with source elements

Tags: html, joomla, tinymce

Joomla 3 strips out unsupported HTML tags. How can I prevent Joomla from filtering out picture elements similar to the one below:

```
<picture>
   <source type="image/svg" src="logo.svg" />
   <source type="image/png" src="logo.png" />
   <img src="logo.gif" alt="RadWolf, Inc." />
</picture>
```

Update:
I tried adding picture[class], source[class|srcset|type|media|sizes] but the html markup still gets filtered out.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an editor problem not Joomla!. If you are using JCE editor then :

- check in *Editor Global Configuration* the values for *Validate HTML* and *Doctype*
- check in *your JCE profile -> Editor parameters -> Filesystem -> Uploader engines* that HTML5 is selected
- check in your *JCE profile -> Plugin parameters -> Image Manager -> Permitted Files Extensions* that the extensions you want are permitted

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @jcm69. I'm not using JCE just TinyMCE. Should I install that? or can this be achieved solely through TinyMCE?

Comment: You're not obliged to download JCE editor. JCE is based on TinyMCE. So I guess this options in JCE are inherited from TinyMCE. Search `TinyMCE HTML5` and you'll plenty of solutions. But if you install JCE editor, the solutions I proposed should work ;)

Comment: I can stick with TinyMCE since it appears I can get it work, please see my updated question.

Comment: Sorry, I search a little bit with no success. Even `*[*]` doesn't worked for me... May be you should try the [TinyMCE forum](http://community.tinymce.com/forum/)

Comment: Thanks will do that.

Comment: May be a good idea to post the response here. If you find it. I hope so !

Comment: No problem. Will do as soon as I have a solution. As temporary solution, I'm using JCE with validation turned off.